# How to display list content from a different site on a modern page?

Tags: office-365, modern-experience

I have two Office 365 Groups. There is a custom list on one group site that I'd like to display on the home page of the other Group's site. Both sites are modern sites, and the home page of the target site is using a modern page.

There is a "highlighted content" web part, but it does not yet provide the option to specify which fields to display, which makes it an extremely limited option.

The RSS web part does not seem to support RSS feeds for SharePoint lists. Power BI would work, but that's a pretty drastic option to be able to show a few items from a list. Any other option I'm overlooking?