# Is there a way to show documents across different site collections in Modern UI on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, configuration, modern-experience

The highlighted content web part does work with this question, sort of. But is there a Content Search Web Part equivalent in Modern UI on SharePoint Online?

My main requirement is to show a list of documents, or a view of a document library, from one Site collection, on multiple site collections.

We are trying to have a central location from where all the procedures are accessed from, but have the procedures stored in their respective department sites. So we are trying to roll up all the different content to a central Communication Site.

In Classic UI, I would have used a Content Search Webpart and scoped it to a content type; but Modern Experience does not have this (yet).

Maybe there is an SPFX web part way to do this?

My question is very similar to [this one here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245126/how-to-display-list-content-from-a-different-site-on-a-modern-page).

Answer (score 2):

There is no another OOB modern web part except Highlighted content web part to roll up documents from multiple sites.

Yes you can deploy SPFx.

Tools “react search web part” as a convenience to you:

https://github.com/estruyf/Search-WP-SPFx

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-search

As an alternative in a modern page, you can use Content Search web part in a classic page and then use Embed modern web part to display the content of this classic page in the modern page.

Comment: Thank you. I just came across that web part as well and added an answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

For any users that come across this question in the future. There is an SP Dev solution for this. There was a webcast done by the PNP Dev community on 5th March 2019 ([linked here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/pnp-webcast-sharepoint-framework-modern-search-web-part/)).

The source code is on Github in the SP Dev solutions ([here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ModernSearch/react-search-refiners)). It is called Modern Search. [Here is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g41nvRVwtds) to the 1 hour tutorial they posted on YouTube.

Here is a snip from the documentation:

**Summary**

This solution allows you to build user friendly SharePoint search experiences using SPFx in the modern interface. The main features include:

- Fully customizable SharePoint search query like the good old Content Search Web Part.
- Can either use a static query or be connected to a search box component using SPFx dynamic data.
- Live templating system with Handlebar to meet your requirements in terms of UI + builtin list and tiles templates. Can alos use template from an external file.
- Search results includings previews for Office documents and Office 365 videos.
- Customizable refiners supporting multilingual values for taxonomy based filters.
- Sortable results (unique field).
- Refiners Web Part.
- Results paging.
- SharePoint best bets support.
- Search query enhancement with NLP tools (like Microsoft LUIS).